# PDF no se genera correctamente al cargar imágenes con IText7 y .net core 5

Tags: .net, .net-core, itext

espero se encuentren bien.

Actualmente me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación que debe de generar el código de barras en base un código externo. A la hora de generar el PDF y abrirlo, indica que el formado del PDF no es correcto, estoy utilizando IText 7.1.10 para generar el PDF.

Nuggets utilizados: IText7 v7.1.10, BarcodeLib v2.4.0

.Net Core 5 MVC

Adjunto el código que tengo hasta ahora.

Controller.

```
public IActionResult sendBarCodeTest()
{
    //llamo el nombre de la impresora.

    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        list.Add("TESTE123135153");
        list.Add("TESTE123135154");
        list.Add("TESTE123135155");

        //Propiedades para crear el PDF
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        PdfWriter pw = new PdfWriter(ms);
        PdfDocument pd = new PdfDocument(pw);
        Document doc = new Document(pd);
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            byte[] encodedByte = generateBarCode(item);

            iText.Layout.Element.Image img = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(ImageDataFactory.Create(encodedByte,true));

            paragraph.Add(img);

        }

        doc.Add(paragraph);
        var bytes = ms.ToArray();
        doc.Close();

        return File(bytes, "application/pdf", "barcodes.pdf");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }


}
```

Metodo generateBarCode

```
private byte[] generateBarCode(string vin)
        {
            try
            {
                BarcodeLib.Barcode barcode = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();
                System.Drawing.Image img = barcode.Encode(TYPE.CODE128, vin, Color.Black, Color.White, 250, 100);
                var data = ConvertImageToArray(img);

                return data;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Ocurrio un error al intentar generar el código de barras");
            }

        }
```

Metodo ConvertImageToArray.

```
    private byte [] ConvertImageToArray(System.Drawing.Image img)
    {

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Agradezco de antemano la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No logré resolver el problema implementando IText7, por lo que migré a ItextSharp y realicé cambios en el código que imprime el PDF. Adjunto las modificaciones realizadas al código que imprime el PDF.

```
public IActionResult sendBarCodeTest()
        {
            //llamo el nombre de la impresora.

            List<string> list = new List<string>();

            var impresora = _VinService.AST_ParametrosImpresion();
            //Obtenemos el listado de vines para el proyecto.

            try
            {
                list.Add("TESTE123135153");
                list.Add("TESTE123135154");
                list.Add("TESTE123135155");

                //Propiedades para crear el PDF
                Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);
                MemoryStream mi = new MemoryStream();
                var writter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, mi);
                doc.AddAuthor("test");
                doc.AddTitle("Barcodes generated");
                doc.Open();

                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    byte[] encodedByte = generateBarCode(item);
                    var img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(encodedByte);
                    doc.Add(img);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    {
                        doc.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                        doc.Add(new Phrase("\n"));

                    }
                }

                doc.Close();
                writter.Close();

                var myFile = mi.ToArray();

                return File(myFile, "application/vnd", "barcode.pdf");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }


        }
```